# how to use android broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Here below is an example of service, activity and broadcast receiver. An activity is a setting that make changes to a service. The broadcast receiver listens to changes in settings and update service. learner2learner

```
public class xService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public static void setEnableNotification(int command) {
        Log.i("EnableNotification","Updated");
        if (command == 0)
            enableNotification = true;
        ...
    }
}
```

The method below is a part of an activity that sends broadcast:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(NotifyServiceReceiver.ACTION);       
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
}   
final String ACTION="broadcast_settings";
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);

    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.switchNotification:
        if(switchNotification.isChecked()==true)
        {       
            intent.putExtra("EnableNotification", 0);
            Log.i("Security365","Notification is enabled.");
        }
        else if ....
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        break;
    }
```

The part below is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class xReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final String ACTION="broadcast_settings";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){

            int enableNotification = intent.getIntExtra("EnableNotification", 0);

            if (enableNotification == 0)
                Serurity365Service.setEnableNotification(0);
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Mainfest

```
    <receiver android:name=".xReceiver" android:enabled="true"></receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, the block

```
 if(switchNotification.isChecked()==true)
    {       
        intent.putExtra("EnableNotification", 1);
        Log.i("Security365","Notification is enabled.");
    }
```

is setting the `EnableNotification` to `1` in the intent used from `sendBroadcast`

In your broadcast receiver, you have

```
 int enableNotification = intent
            .getIntExtra("EnableNotification", 1);

    if (enableNotification == 0)
        Serurity365Service.setEnableNotification(0);
```

So it says to retrieve the extra `EnableNotification` and if no value, return the default value of `1` and then you never enter your `if (enableNotification == 0)` statement.

To be sure your broadcast receiver works correctly, add a log statement at the beginning of your receiver in the `onReceive` method.

**EDIT**:

Also the `AndroidMANIFEST.xml` has a tag `<manifest>` that declares a `package`.

For example

`<manifest package="com.hello.world" ...`

When you declare the receiver in the manifest, the `.` like in `.xReceiver` means that `xReceiver.java` should be located in the package `com.hello.world`.

If you have in a different package, specify the full name or relatiive to the `package`  declared in `<manifest`

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#nm)

Comment: ihave another statement as well for if (enableNotification == 1)

Comment: You have added the Log.i before `if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){` right ?

Answer (score 0):

you are sending broadcast in a wrong way. You should send it as below:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("your_action");

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.switchNotification:
            if(switchNotification.isChecked()==true)
            {       
                intent.putExtra("EnableNotification", 1);
                Log.i("Security365","Notification is enabled.");
            }
            else if ....
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            break;
        }
}
```

and receive it as:

```
 public class xReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     if(intent.getACtion().equals("your_action"){
        int enableNotification = intent
                .getIntExtra("EnableNotification", 1);

        if (enableNotification == 0)
            Serurity365Service.setEnableNotification(0);
        ...
   }
} 
}
```

update you Androidmanifest.xml too:

```
<receiver android:name=".xReceiver" android:enabled="true">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="your_action" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you. But, what is "your_action"? can you give example?

Comment: this is the string you send in your broadcast to distinguish between different actions. http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

Comment: ohh yeah, you also need to update your receiver in manifest. check my answer once again. i've updated it